# Issue with Upgrading tomcat of liferay

Tags: liferay

I have updated the version of tomcate to 7.0.67 with Liferay 6.1 . 
when I start tomcat then only an empty page is displayed under localhost:8080:

Here is ouput of catalina.out:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:677)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1939)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/bean/BeanLocator
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocator
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
        ... 24 more
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Remember that along after updating the Tomcat server itself you should also update the configuration files (/conf/*.xml and /ROOT/WEB-INF/*xml etc). Otherwise your Tomcat won't "know" anything about the Liferay. Try to compare those configs with the ones you had on your old server and make the needed changes.

Comment: unfortunately has not helped

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the [Installing Liferay on Tomcat 7](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/installing-liferay-on-tomcat-7#tomcat-configuration) guide? You may have skipped the part where the guide tells you add `${catalina.base}/lib/ext/*.jar` to the `common.loader` property.

Comment: Agreed. This is most likely the issue. One way to figure out what exactly is changed in the bundles is to download the exact same version of tomcat and do a directory-diff. Ignore the 'webapps', 'temp' and 'work' directories, and inspect the others.